# How to run PHP class function based on $_POST method data?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on theme demo import and my goal is to import demo data based on selection. For example there are two choices for user to chose from, If he/she selects 1st then the import process will import data for 1st demo only while if he/she selects 2nd then demo for second option will be imported.
I am doing in this way, with jquery ajax sending `$_POST` data to my import class page, then I can grab those values and can set my file paths according to those values. But, I am unable to set values inside class properties based on `$_POST` values.

I am doing this way:

```
if($_POST){
    $demo = $_POST['demo'];
    echo $demo; 
}
```

Now, on based on this $demo value I want to chose my file paths. Bun unfortunately I am unable to do so, I don't know where am I doing wrong ?

```
class import {

        public $theme_options = 'custom';

    public $value = 'mydata';
}
```

I just want to set the value of $value property with my `$_POST` value.

How can I do this ?

How can I do that just setting my class property value with my $_POST value ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set your desired values to class properties using constructor or any other function which you are calling using ajax.

```
class import {

    public $theme_options;
    public $value;

    function __construct($dataFromAjax){
         $this->value = $dataFromAjax;
    }
}
```

OR

```
class import {

        public $theme_options;
        public $value;

        function callableUsingAjax($dataFromAjax){
             $this->value = $dataFromAjax;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess You can modify this parameters as per your need, using `$_POST` superglobal.

Comment: can you guide me that how can I start my import process again as with e.perventDefault() its not working any more ?

Comment: @laraib sorry I couldn't understand your question fully. are you facing problem in your js? include that part of code to your question then.

Comment: Rahman bro I want to run my class object but problem is that once I run it does not here is my question url on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38473392/how-to-run-my-class-object-with-ajax-jquery-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.  When you call your function to store the data before it you can change the value for your public variable like this.

```
class import {

    public $theme_options = 'custom';

    public $value = 'mydata';

    function YourFunction()
    {
        $this->value = $_POST['demo'];
        // Your Code Here;
    }
}
```