# How to run my class object with ajax jquery in PHP

Tags: wordpress

I am developing a theme and currently working on import data process. Radium one click import working really fine for my but I want to add some minor change. I have two demos for my client, family law and personal law. I want to give her a choice so that she can install which one she wants in single install. Currently me demo was installed with button click, I just disabled that functionality by `jquery e.perventDefault() function` to check which button is clicked so that I can set my demo files accordingly. 
Its working good and I am able to send my file names properly through `ajax $_POST` and getting those values in my `PHP` file.

The real issue is that it never imports my data any more. It sets my file names but does not start my import process. How can I start my import process again ?
Here is my code.

```
$('.import-process .import-start').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('family-law');
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url:"path to my file",
            data: "family=family",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("message sent!");
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

With this data I am just getting my file names and nothing else at all. Now kindly let me know how can I start my import process either in PHP file or in js file I am totally no where by now. Thanks
Here is full code:

```
<?php

/**
 * Class Radium_Theme_Importer
 *
 * This class provides the capability to import demo content as well as import widgets and WordPress menus
 *
 * @since 0.0.2
 *
 * @category RadiumFramework
 * @package  NewsCore WP
 * @author   Franklin M Gitonga
 * @link     http://radiumthemes.com/
 *
 */

 // Exit if accessed directly
 if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

 // Don't duplicate me!
 if ( !class_exists( 'Radium_Theme_Importer' ) ) {

    class Radium_Theme_Importer {

        public $theme_options_framework = 'radium'; //supports radium framework and option tree

        public $theme_options_file;

        public $widgets;

        public $content_demo;

        public $flag_as_imported = array( 'content' => false, 'menus' => false, 'options' => false, 'widgets' =>false );


        public $imported_demos = array();

        public $add_admin_menu = true;


        private static $instance;

        public function __construct() {

            self::$instance = $this;

           echo $this->demo_files_path      = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_demo_files_path', $this->demo_files_path);
            if($this->me == 'kami'){
                echo $this->theme_options_file  = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_theme_options_file', $this->demo_files_path . $this->theme_options_file_name);
            } else {
                echo $this->theme_options_file = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_theme_options_file', $this->demo_files_path . $this->theme_options_file_name1);
            }

            echo $this->widgets                 = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_widgets_file', $this->demo_files_path . $this->widgets_file_name);

            $this->content_demo         = apply_filters('radium_theme_importer_content_demo_file', $this->demo_files_path . $this->content_demo_file_name);

            $this->imported_demos = get_option( 'radium_imported_demo' );

            if( $this->theme_options_framework == 'optiontree' ) {
                $this->theme_option_name = ot_options_id();
            }

            if( $this->add_admin_menu ) add_action( 'admin_menu', array($this, 'add_admin') );

            add_filter( 'add_post_metadata', array( $this, 'check_previous_meta' ), 10, 5 );

            add_action( 'radium_import_end', array( $this, 'after_wp_importer' ) );

        }


        public function add_admin() {

            add_submenu_page('themes.php', "Import Demo Data", "Import Demo Data", 'switch_themes', 'radium_demo_installer', array($this, 'demo_installer'));

        }

        public function check_previous_meta( $continue, $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique ) {

            $old_value = get_metadata( 'post', $post_id, $meta_key );

            if ( count( $old_value ) == 1 ) {

                if ( $old_value[0] === $meta_value ) {

                    return false;

                } elseif ( $old_value[0] !== $meta_value ) {

                    update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
                    return false;

                }

            }

        }

        public function after_wp_importer() {

            do_action( 'radium_importer_after_content_import');

            update_option( 'radium_imported_demo', $this->flag_as_imported );

        }

        public function intro_html() {

            ?>

            <div style="background-color: #F5FAFD; margin:10px 0;padding: 5px 10px;color: #0C518F;border: 2px solid #CAE0F3; clear:both; width:90%; line-height:18px;">
                <p class="tie_message_hint">Importing demo data (post, pages, images, theme settings, ...) is the easiest way to setup your theme. It will
                allow you to quickly edit everything instead of creating content from scratch. When you import the data following things will happen:</p>

                  <ul style="padding-left: 20px;list-style-position: inside;list-style-type: square;}">
                      <li>No existing posts, pages, categories, images, custom post types or any other data will be deleted or modified .</li>
                      <li>No WordPress settings will be modified .</li>
                      <li>Posts, pages, some images, some widgets and menus will get imported .</li>
                      <li>Images will be downloaded from our server, these images are copyrighted and are for demo use only .</li>
                      <li>Please click import only once and wait, it can take a couple of minutes</li>
                  </ul>
             </div>

             <div style="background-color: #F5FAFD; margin:10px 0;padding: 5px 10px;color: #0C518F;border: 2px solid #CAE0F3; clear:both; width:90%; line-height:18px;"><p class="tie_message_hint">Before you begin, make sure all the required plugins are activated.</p></div>

             <?php

             if( !empty($this->imported_demos) ) { ?>

                <div style="background-color: #FAFFFB; margin:10px 0;padding: 5px 10px;color: #8AB38A;border: 2px solid #a1d3a2; clear:both; width:90%; line-height:18px;">
                    <p><?php _e('Demo already imported', 'radium'); ?></p>
                </div><?php
                //return;

              }
        }

        public function demo_installer() {

            $action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';

            if( !empty($this->imported_demos ) ) {

                $button_text = __('Import Again', 'radium');

            } else {

                $button_text = __('Import Demo Data', 'radium');

            }

            ?><div id="icon-tools" class="icon32"><br></div>
            <h2>Import Demo Data</h2>

           <div class="radium-importer-wrap" data-demo-id="1"  data-nonce="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('radium-demo-code'); ?>">

                <form method="post">
                    <?php $this->intro_html(); ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="demononce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce('radium-demo-code'); ?>" />
                    <input name="reset" class="panel-save button-primary radium-import-start" type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_text ; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="demo-data" />

                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div class="radium-importer-message clear">
                        <?php if( 'demo-data' == $action && check_admin_referer('radium-demo-code' , 'demononce')){
                            $this->process_imports();
                        } ?>
                    </div>
                </form>

            </div>

            <br />
            <br /><?php

        }
        public function process_imports($mine = true, $content = true, $options = true, $widgets = true) {

            if ( $content && !empty( $this->content_demo ) && is_file( $this->content_demo ) ) {
                $this->set_demo_data( $this->content_demo );
            }

            if ( $options && !empty( $this->theme_options_file ) && is_file( $this->theme_options_file ) ) {
                $this->set_demo_theme_options( $this->theme_options_file );
            }

            if ( $options ) {
                $this->set_demo_menus();
            }

            if ( $widgets && !empty( $this->widgets ) && is_file( $this->widgets ) ) {
                $this->process_widget_import_file( $this->widgets );
            }

            if($mine){
            $this->import_options();
            }

            do_action( 'radium_import_end');

        }
        public function add_widget_to_sidebar($sidebar_slug, $widget_slug, $count_mod, $widget_settings = array()){

            $sidebars_widgets = get_option('sidebars_widgets');

            if(!isset($sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_slug]))
               $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_slug] = array('_multiwidget' => 1);

            $newWidget = get_option('widget_'.$widget_slug);

            if(!is_array($newWidget))
                $newWidget = array();

            $count = count($newWidget)+1+$count_mod;
            $sidebars_widgets[$sidebar_slug][] = $widget_slug.'-'.$count;

            $newWidget[$count] = $widget_settings;

            update_option('sidebars_widgets', $sidebars_widgets);
            update_option('widget_'.$widget_slug, $newWidget);

        }

        public function set_demo_data( $file ) {

            if ( !defined('WP_LOAD_IMPORTERS') ) define('WP_LOAD_IMPORTERS', true);

            require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/import.php';

            $importer_error = false;

            if ( !class_exists( 'WP_Importer' ) ) {

                $class_wp_importer = ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-importer.php';

                if ( file_exists( $class_wp_importer ) ){

                    require_once($class_wp_importer);

                } else {

                    $importer_error = true;

                }

            }

            if ( !class_exists( 'WP_Import' ) ) {

                $class_wp_import = dirname( __FILE__ ) .'/wordpress-importer.php';

                if ( file_exists( $class_wp_import ) )
                    require_once($class_wp_import);
                else
                    $importer_error = true;

            }

            if($importer_error){

                die("Error on import");

            } else {

                if(!is_file( $file )){

                    echo "The XML file containing the dummy content is not available or could not be read .. You might want to try to set the file permission to chmod 755.<br/>If this doesn't work please use the Wordpress importer and import the XML file (should be located in your download .zip: Sample Content folder) manually ";

                } else {

                    $wp_import = new WP_Import();
                    $wp_import->fetch_attachments = true;
                    $wp_import->import( $file );
                    $this->flag_as_imported['content'] = true;

                }

            }

            do_action( 'radium_importer_after_theme_content_import');

        }

        /** Import Options Hook added by kami*/
        public function import_options() {
            //$data = $_POST['data'];
            $data = $options_export;
            $data = base64_decode( $data );
            $data = json_decode( $data, true );

            if ( isset( $data ) ) {
                foreach ( $data as $key => $value ) {
                    update_option( $key, wp_kses_post( stripcslashes( $value) ) );
                }
            }

            //die();
        }
        /** import action ends **/

        public function set_demo_menus() {}

        public function set_demo_theme_options( $file ) {

            // Does the File exist?
            if ( file_exists( $file ) ) {

                // Get file contents and decode
                $data = file_get_contents( $file );

                if( $this->theme_options_framework == 'radium') {

                    //radium framework
                    $data = unserialize( trim($data, '###') );

                } elseif( $this->theme_options_framework == 'optiontree' ) {

                    //option tree import
                    $data = $this->optiontree_decode($data);

                    update_option( ot_options_id(), $data );

                    $this->flag_as_imported['options'] = true;

                } else {

                    //other frameworks
                    //$data = json_decode( $data, true );
                    $data = maybe_unserialize( $data );

                }

                // Only if there is data
                if ( !empty( $data ) || is_array( $data ) ) {

                    // Hook before import
                    $data = apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_theme_options', $data );

                    update_option( $this->theme_option_name, $data );

                    $this->flag_as_imported['options'] = true;
                }

                do_action( 'radium_importer_after_theme_options_import', $this->demo_files_path );

            } else {

                wp_die(
                    __( 'Theme options Import file could not be found. Please try again.', 'radium' ),
                    '',
                    array( 'back_link' => true )
                );
            }

        }

        function available_widgets() {

            global $wp_registered_widget_controls;

            $widget_controls = $wp_registered_widget_controls;

            $available_widgets = array();

            foreach ( $widget_controls as $widget ) {

                if ( ! empty( $widget['id_base'] ) && ! isset( $available_widgets[$widget['id_base']] ) ) { // no dupes

                    $available_widgets[$widget['id_base']]['id_base'] = $widget['id_base'];
                    $available_widgets[$widget['id_base']]['name'] = $widget['name'];

                }

            }

            return apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_widget_available_widgets', $available_widgets );

        }
        function process_widget_import_file( $file ) {

            // File exists?
            if ( ! file_exists( $file ) ) {
                wp_die(
                    __( 'Widget Import file could not be found. Please try again.', 'radium' ),
                    '',
                    array( 'back_link' => true )
                );
            }

            // Get file contents and decode
            $data = file_get_contents( $file );
            $data = json_decode( $data );

            // Delete import file
            //unlink( $file );

            // Import the widget data
            // Make results available for display on import/export page
            $this->widget_import_results = $this->import_widgets( $data );

        }
        public function import_widgets( $data ) {

            global $wp_registered_sidebars;

            // Have valid data?
            // If no data or could not decode
            if ( empty( $data ) || ! is_object( $data ) ) {
                return;
            }

            // Hook before import
            $data = apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_widget_data', $data );

            // Get all available widgets site supports
            $available_widgets = $this->available_widgets();

            // Get all existing widget instances
            $widget_instances = array();
            foreach ( $available_widgets as $widget_data ) {
                $widget_instances[$widget_data['id_base']] = get_option( 'widget_' . $widget_data['id_base'] );
            }

            // Begin results
            $results = array();

            // Loop import data's sidebars
            foreach ( $data as $sidebar_id => $widgets ) {

                // Skip inactive widgets
                // (should not be in export file)
                if ( 'wp_inactive_widgets' == $sidebar_id ) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Check if sidebar is available on this site
                // Otherwise add widgets to inactive, and say so
                if ( isset( $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id] ) ) {
                    $sidebar_available = true;
                    $use_sidebar_id = $sidebar_id;
                    $sidebar_message_type = 'success';
                    $sidebar_message = '';
                } else {
                    $sidebar_available = false;
                    $use_sidebar_id = 'wp_inactive_widgets'; // add to inactive if sidebar does not exist in theme
                    $sidebar_message_type = 'error';
                    $sidebar_message = __( 'Sidebar does not exist in theme (using Inactive)', 'radium' );
                }

                // Result for sidebar
                $results[$sidebar_id]['name'] = ! empty( $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id]['name'] ) ? $wp_registered_sidebars[$sidebar_id]['name'] : $sidebar_id; // sidebar name if theme supports it; otherwise ID
                $results[$sidebar_id]['message_type'] = $sidebar_message_type;
                $results[$sidebar_id]['message'] = $sidebar_message;
                $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'] = array();

                // Loop widgets
                foreach ( $widgets as $widget_instance_id => $widget ) {

                    $fail = false;

                    // Get id_base (remove -# from end) and instance ID number
                    $id_base = preg_replace( '/-[0-9]+$/', '', $widget_instance_id );
                    $instance_id_number = str_replace( $id_base . '-', '', $widget_instance_id );

                    // Does site support this widget?
                    if ( ! $fail && ! isset( $available_widgets[$id_base] ) ) {
                        $fail = true;
                        $widget_message_type = 'error';
                        $widget_message = __( 'Site does not support widget', 'radium' ); // explain why widget not imported
                    }

                    // Filter to modify settings before import
                    // Do before identical check because changes may make it identical to end result (such as URL replacements)
                    $widget = apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_widget_settings', $widget );

                    // Does widget with identical settings already exist in same sidebar?
                    if ( ! $fail && isset( $widget_instances[$id_base] ) ) {

                        // Get existing widgets in this sidebar
                        $sidebars_widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' );
                        $sidebar_widgets = isset( $sidebars_widgets[$use_sidebar_id] ) ? $sidebars_widgets[$use_sidebar_id] : array(); // check Inactive if that's where will go

                        // Loop widgets with ID base
                        $single_widget_instances = ! empty( $widget_instances[$id_base] ) ? $widget_instances[$id_base] : array();
                        foreach ( $single_widget_instances as $check_id => $check_widget ) {

                            // Is widget in same sidebar and has identical settings?
                            if ( in_array( "$id_base-$check_id", $sidebar_widgets ) && (array) $widget == $check_widget ) {

                                $fail = true;
                                $widget_message_type = 'warning';
                                $widget_message = __( 'Widget already exists', 'radium' ); // explain why widget not imported
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // No failure
                    if ( ! $fail ) {

                        // Add widget instance
                        $single_widget_instances = get_option( 'widget_' . $id_base ); // all instances for that widget ID base, get fresh every time
                        $single_widget_instances = ! empty( $single_widget_instances ) ? $single_widget_instances : array( '_multiwidget' => 1 ); // start fresh if have to
                        $single_widget_instances[] = (array) $widget; // add it

                        // Get the key it was given
                        end( $single_widget_instances );
                        $new_instance_id_number = key( $single_widget_instances );

                        // If key is 0, make it 1
                        // When 0, an issue can occur where adding a widget causes data from other widget to load, and the widget doesn't stick (reload wipes it)
                        if ( '0' === strval( $new_instance_id_number ) ) {
                            $new_instance_id_number = 1;
                            $single_widget_instances[$new_instance_id_number] = $single_widget_instances[0];
                            unset( $single_widget_instances[0] );
                        }

                        // Move _multiwidget to end of array for uniformity
                        if ( isset( $single_widget_instances['_multiwidget'] ) ) {
                            $multiwidget = $single_widget_instances['_multiwidget'];
                            unset( $single_widget_instances['_multiwidget'] );
                            $single_widget_instances['_multiwidget'] = $multiwidget;
                        }

                        // Update option with new widget
                        update_option( 'widget_' . $id_base, $single_widget_instances );

                        // Assign widget instance to sidebar
                        $sidebars_widgets = get_option( 'sidebars_widgets' ); // which sidebars have which widgets, get fresh every time
                        $new_instance_id = $id_base . '-' . $new_instance_id_number; // use ID number from new widget instance
                        $sidebars_widgets[$use_sidebar_id][] = $new_instance_id; // add new instance to sidebar
                        update_option( 'sidebars_widgets', $sidebars_widgets ); // save the amended data
                        // Success message
                        if ( $sidebar_available ) {
                            $widget_message_type = 'success';
                            $widget_message = __( 'Imported', 'radium' );
                        } else {
                            $widget_message_type = 'warning';
                            $widget_message = __( 'Imported to Inactive', 'radium' );
                        }
                    }
                    // Result for widget instance
                    $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_instance_id]['name'] = isset( $available_widgets[$id_base]['name'] ) ? $available_widgets[$id_base]['name'] : $id_base; // widget name or ID if name not available (not supported by site)
                    $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_instance_id]['title'] = $widget->title ? $widget->title : __( 'No Title', 'radium' ); // show "No Title" if widget instance is untitled
                    $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_instance_id]['message_type'] = $widget_message_type;
                    $results[$sidebar_id]['widgets'][$widget_instance_id]['message'] = $widget_message;
                }
            }
            $this->flag_as_imported['widgets'] = true;
            // Hook after import
            do_action( 'radium_theme_import_widget_after_import' );
            // Return results
            return apply_filters( 'radium_theme_import_widget_results', $results );
        }
        public function optiontree_decode( $value ) {

            $func = 'base64' . '_decode';
            $prepared_data = maybe_unserialize( $func( $value ) );

            return $prepared_data;
        }

    }//class
}//function_exists
?>
```

Here is my INIT class

```
<?php
```

if($_POST){
    $theHash = $_POST['hashString'];
    echo $theHash; echo "the hash value is";
}
/**
 * Version 0.0.3
 *
 * This file is just an example you can copy it to your theme and modify it to fit your own needs.
 * Watch the paths though.
 */
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// Don't duplicate me!
if ( !class_exists( 'Radium_Theme_Demo_Data_Importer' ) ) {

```
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/importer/radium-importer.php' ); //load admin theme data importer

class Radium_Theme_Demo_Data_Importer extends Radium_Theme_Importer {

    /**
     * Set framewok
     *
     * options that can be used are 'default', 'radium' or 'optiontree'
     *
     * @since 0.0.3
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $theme_options_framework = 'radium';

public $me = 'dani';

    /**
     * Holds a copy of the object for easy reference.
     *
     * @since 0.0.1
     *
     * @var object
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * Set the key to be used to store theme options
     *
     * @since 0.0.2
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $theme_option_name       = 'my_theme_options_name'; //set theme options name here (key used to save theme options). Optiontree option name will be set automatically

    /**
     * Set name of the theme options file
     *
     * @since 0.0.2
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $theme_options_file_name = 'theme_options.txt';
    public $theme_options_file_name1 = 'theme_options1.txt';

    /**
     * Set name of the widgets json file
     *
     * @since 0.0.2
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $widgets_file_name       = 'widgets.json';

    /**
     * Set name of the content file
     *
     * @since 0.0.2
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $content_demo_file_name  = 'content.xml';

    /**
     * Holds a copy of the widget settings
     *
     * @since 0.0.2
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $widget_import_results;

    /**
     * Constructor. Hooks all interactions to initialize the class.
     *
     * @since 0.0.1
     */
    public function __construct() {

        $this->demo_files_path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/demo-files/'; //can

        self::$instance = $this;
        parent::__construct();

    }

    /**
     * Add menus - the menus listed here largely depend on the ones registered in the theme
     *
     * @since 0.0.1
     */
    public function set_demo_menus(){

        // Menus to Import and assign - you can remove or add as many as you want
        $top_menu    = get_term_by('name', 'Top Menu', 'nav_menu');
        $main_menu   = get_term_by('name', 'Main Menu', 'nav_menu');
        $footer_menu = get_term_by('name', 'Main Menu', 'nav_menu');

        set_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations', array(
                'top-menu' => $top_menu->term_id,
                'primary' => $main_menu->term_id,
                'footer-menu' => $footer_menu->term_id
            )
        );

        $this->flag_as_imported['menus'] = true;

    }

}

new Radium_Theme_Demo_Data_Importer;

}
```

Now here is my question again ... How can I extend this code so that I can import data based on my selection. For that I can send that selection by `ajax post` as well. Thanks hope that's enough info by now.

Comment: I'm afraid I may've to see your script to be able to help you. anyway I may give you an abstract idea and i guess you will be able to it from that. But first tell me how your import process work?

Comment: here is my over all code for that .... let me paste that code in my question

Comment: this above is my full import class and here is my extended class as well

Comment: just tell me which function you called previously from ajax to start your importing process and which one you are calling now to pass that value?

Comment: did you call your `Radium_Theme_Demo_Data_Importer` class script to initiate importing process previously? and what are you doing now to pass that value? and please format your init class properly.

Comment: no, previously it was working without ajax just with php .... but I want to provide my client a list of option from where she can chose which demo she wants family law or personal law etc ?

Comment: this part actually works I think new Radium_Theme_Demo_Data_Importer;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117782/discussion-between-asif-rahaman-and-laraib).